# Why function-modified lists don't change when seen in the main file?

Tags: python, list, function

**Context**: I needed to randomly erase some precise element of a few lists of numbers, extracting some random indexes and saving them in a set called *aleaindex* (done, it properly works, thanks to some SO users' help). Now, I'd like to substitute the old lists *a*, *b*, etc with the new, eventually shorter ones *newa*, *newb*, etc. Here is the function:

```
def myfunction(N, other_parameters, a, b, c):
    ...
    while (...):
        aleaindex.add(random.randint(..., ...))
    ...
    new_a = [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in aleaindex]
    while a: a.pop()
        a = new_a[:]
    ...
```

and so on for the other lists *b*, *c*, etc.

**Problem**: the function seems to correctly modify them within the module (checked by printing) but then, when I print the modified lists *outside* the module, that is in the "main" file, lists are as they had not modified. Where am I wrong?

Comment: There is no function in the code you have posted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the lines of code I posted are within the function! The function doesn't return anything, it should just modify the lists. Previous versions of the function, where I didn't put these lines, worked properly (i.e. lists were modified outside the module, too).

Comment: Look, just post a sufficient amount of code to demonstrate the problem, and the erroneous output, and the desired output. See http://sssce.org

Comment: OK, tell me if it is enough: I just avoided writing a lot of stuff like the condition of the while loop or the values I put into the _aleaindex_ set (those parts work very well). Thanks

Comment: Given that your question seems to be about what happens outside of the function, I would say that this is not enough. If it is enough, then probably word your question differently. Think of code, input, and output as the primary elements of your question, and text as a (completely necessary, but not sufficient) supporting element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line:

```
a=new_a[:]
```

overwrites the variable `a` with a new object. Outside the function or module, the old object is still pointed at by `a` (or whatever it was called there). Try:

```
new_a = [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in aleaindex]
while a:
    a.pop()
    a[:] = new_a[:]
```

#### Explanation

To see this, just try the following.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[:] = [2,3]
>>> print b
[2, 3]
>>> a = [5]
>>> print b
[2, 3]
```

### Example in function!

If the variable is mutable (and a normal list is), this works:

```
>>> def f(a):
...     a[0] = 2
>>> b = [3]
>>> f(b)
>>> print b
[2]
```

Variables are not passed by value - you can edit a mutable value.

Comment: It overwrites the same variable with a new object.

Comment: Nitpick, `a[:] = new_a[:]` can just be `a[:] = new_a`.

Comment: OK @Henry, thanks to your help I managed to obtain what I desired. Only, I had to put a[:]=new_a[:] _outside_ the loop. Again, thank you (and the other guys, too) for helping

Comment: `a[:] = new_a[:]` is the same as `a[:] = new_a` but not the same as (3) `a = new_a[:]` which is again different from (4) `a = new_a`. The first two modify the object currently in `a` to have the same contents as `new_a`. The second two assign a new object to `a`, which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what you are trying to do but from your snippets you are clearly lost. Your code does not make much sense and there are more more than one problem. Nonetheless, the problem you asked about - why the list is not fully changed? - seems to be related to this loop:

```
while a: a.pop()
    a = new_a[:]
```

Suppose we call your function this way:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
myfunction(N, other_parameters, list1, [], [])
```

What will happen is, when you call the first line, you will get a variable called `list1` and it will point to a list:

[image: list1 points to a list]

When you call the function `myfunction()`, the function, among other things, create a variable called `a` which will point to the same list pointed by `list1`:

[image: Now a points to the same list as list1]

So far, so good. Then we get at the loop below:

```
while a:
    a.pop()
    a = new_a[:]
```

In the first line of it (`a.pop()`), you get an item out of the list. Since both variables `a` and `list1` points to the same list, you would see the same result...

[image: Removing an item from the list]

...if it were not for the next line of the loop (`a = new_a[:]`). In this line, you are making the `a` variable to point to *another*  list:

[image: a points to another list]

Now, every operation you execute on `a` will be in this list, which is in no way related to `list1`. For example, you can execute `a.pop()` at the next iteration to get it:

[image: Popping from the other list]

However, it makes no sense at all, because the line `a = new_a[:]` will replace the list pointed to `a` *again* for *yet another different list*:

[image: Changing a again?!]

So, what is the solution? I don't know. As I have said, it is not possible (to me, at least) to make sense from your code. You have to reflect a bit more about what you are trying to do and explain it to us, with a bit more of context.

Comment: first of all thanks for your very interesting answer, I'm reading it with interest. Not blame me not to have shown a lot of code, I just thought it was better to make the question as much general as possible, showing what I thought to be the core of the problem. Luckily, I succeeded in solving my problem, even if I'll have to think about the _why_ it should be so a little more (and here your answer will be very useful). Bye!

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in the code you have posted. I suspect the problem is that you are not returning the new value.

Your code likely does something like:

```
a = "foo"

def func():
    a = "bar" # uh-oh this not the same as the global a

func()
```

At this point global `a` is unchanged because the `a` local to `func` is not the same variable.

You want to do:

```
a = "foo"

def func():
    return "bar"

a = func()
```

That code assigns to the `a` in global scope, changing it.

Comment: May I have been misled (I've just started writiing in Python) by the fact that in the previous lines of the function I modified the lists using just _append_ and _insert_, and that worked also globally? And how should I do to return a few lists and to assign the global ones the respective local versions? Thank you!

Comment: @Orso I'm glad you said that, because that means you are on the right track. If you modify a list with `a.append(1)` you are not modifying the variable, you are modifying the object which the variable references. Whatever variable you use to access that particular object, you will get the same object, having the same modifications. If you do `a = [1]` you are changing the object to which `a` refers.

Comment: Great, I begin to see the light! Thanks again, @Marcin !